# Should I create a new table?

Tags: mysql

I have following tables in my database.
{account, post, comment}
an account can have 0 or more posts.
a post can have 0 or more comments.
I want to add the (type of post, e.g Q&A, notice, ads, etc).
Do I need to make a new table for this? (If so, what is the relationship between post and new table?)
OR
Do I create a new column (type) in post table?
I am using PHP and mysql

Comment: You can store the type of post as an extra column right?

Comment: @Pritam Banerjee Just adding a column is enough in my case?

Comment: Yes, one post can be of only one type, right? Or can one single post be of multiple types?

Comment: @Sen Jacob how can I achieve? Above person said that adding a column is enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are completely certain that you will never add any other metadata associated with a post, I might just add another column to the `post` table.  But in reality, you probably will be adding more metadata other than the type, so creating a `postmetadata` table is probably a good idea.  Here is what the schema might look like:

```
id | postid | type | other columns ...
```

You would join this to the `post` table whenever you need to access the metadata.  But for other queries involving only the `post` table the meta table could be ignored.

Comment: If so will id and postid be unique? In my case, a post can have only one type.

Comment: You can add a unique constraint to the `postmetadata` table if you want.  That would enforce only one post per type.  But your original question is whether you need a new column or a new table.

Comment: For now, I have only [type] metadata. But I will create a new table as you said because I may need other metadata in future. Thank you.